# Rails server encountering malloc error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, jruby, mongrel, neo4j, jrubyonrails

I started a new rails/neo4j project and using a generator to create models, controllers, routes, tests and views for a Users model (as detailed in http://neo4j.rubyforge.org/guides/rails3.html).

When I try testing the app using the generated /index/ and /new/ routes, the server crashes and give me the following error:

```
   java(1932,0x10ca89000) malloc: *** error for object 0x7f987a424750: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6
```

Sometimes this happens on /index/ and other times it occurs on /new/. I cannot get all the way through looking at an index of users, creating a new user, and viewing the new user without the server crashing.

I am currently using rails 3.1.0 with mongrel but I get the same error with webrick.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is a problem with your environment. I've never seen this error.
What platform are you using (windows, linux ?), which java version and which JRuby.
Did you use RVM to install JRuby ?